# How convert a HTM document to DOC using Java?

Tags: java, documentation-generation, ms-word

I have a HTM document generated in Java and I want to convert to MS Word document. If I try open the HTM document with MS Word, show me a pop-up with an advertisement and I don't want that. I want that the document show it directly.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

[**Apache POI's HWPF**](http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/index.html) will be able to handle writing to the DOC format.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any open source frameworks which can do this efficiently (There are some like Apache POI but the functionality is limited). But [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/categories/java-components/aspose.words-for-java/default.aspx) has a commercial product and it is awesome for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say attempt this.  Now, this is under the assumption that if you were to take the same HTM file, change the extension to DOC and it opens fine.  If you're getting the pop-up from opening the file through Microsoft Word and it's HTM, then I don't know.
http://www.javadb.com/how-to-rename-a-file-change-file-name